# How call whatApp intent from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I have been struggling in this for 2days, can anybody give a suggestion on how to solve it?

This is my WhatsApp2 activity...

```
public class WhatsApp2 extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
public void whatsappSend(){
    try {
        String toNumber = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,    Uri.parse("smsto:" + "" + toNumber+ "?body=" + ""));
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And I am trying to call the `whatsappSend()` from another activity like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends  AppCompatActivity {
    public WhatsApp2 whatsApp2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 public void whatsapp(View view) {
     whatsApp2 = new WhatsApp2();
     whatsApp2.whatsappSend();
  }
 }
```

It `Catch` an exception error in the WhatsApp2 class as:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: In **MainActivity** extends **WhatsApp2**  instead of **AppCompatActivity**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Sniffer thanks for tip, and I just replace AppCompactActivity with WhatsApp2 but its still not working

Answer (score -1):

```
**Try this if you want call whatsapp method from another activity**
//MainActivity



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Whatspp send=new Whatspp(this);
        send.whatsappSend();
    }



}
//Whatspp Class

public class Whatspp  {
    Context _cContext;

    public Whatspp(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        _cContext=mainActivity;
    }

    void whatsappSend() {
        try {
            String toNumber = "**********";
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:" + "" + toNumber + "?body=" + ""));
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            _cContext.startActivity(sendIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "whatsappSend: "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```